# How to enable core PHP extension in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I'm trying to understand the process for enabling an a core extension (dom) in php.  When I run phpinfo, I see '--disable-dom' in the configure command.  Am I supposed to re-install PHP?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: It's a fedora core 4 Amazon ec2 instance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to recompile PHP. Rerun `./configure` with the appropriate parameter (probably `--enable-dom`, but I'm not sure on the param)

Comment: Did you install the php version having `--disable-dom` from sources as well or is it a package from your distribution's repository? If it's a package first look for a php_dom package which will (most likely) provide the dom extension as a shared module. If you really, really have to compile php from source I strongly recommend that you use your distribution's build-system for that. Otherwise you have a (managed) package + custom built version in your system and your version might be overwritten by an update in the repository.

Comment: VolkerK, maybe you can help me out with this- 
I'm on a server I didn't set up, it's an Amazon Ec2 instance, preconfigured w PHP, Apache.  I'm trying to determine if my php is an apache module or cgi installation- I see both a LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so directive in my httpd...php.conf file, but also have directories for /usr/bin/php-cgi.  Does that make sense, thought it would be one or the other?

Comment: If it's an Apache module, do I still do the recompile thing?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to install it from your distributions repository. If not download your php versions source, extract it from the tarball. cd to the directory php/ext and look for a dom folder, cd into that and type phpize then make && make install that will install a dynamic extension for you which you can enable via extension=.so in your php.ini

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as well and let you guys know

Comment: I have to run ./configure before make

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install the dom extension.

```
yum install php-dom
```

and wait for the success message. After which reboot your Amazon instance, which would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian based systems

```
apt-get install php7.4-xml
```