# PHP + SQLite3 on Amazon AMI (EC2)

Tags: php, sqlite, amazon-ec2, installation

I have a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785473/how-to-enable-core-php-extension-in-linux), I want sqlite3 php support on my EC2 (standard Amazon AMI), but PHP was compiled with `--without-sqlite3`.

How can I add sqlite3 support? Its software from repository so I can't just rerun the `./configure` script

More info:

I tried installing it from PECL without much success, and besides it says the version is `0.6 (alpha)` and that sqlite3 support was only briefly available through PECL and should be compiled into the PHP executable (I think). Its confusing.

I also have the PDO extension (some site said sqlite3 is in PDO)

Here is what I tried with PECL:

```
ec2-user[~]> pecl search sqlite
Retrieving data...0%
..Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package    Stable/(Latest) Local
PDO_SQLITE 1.0.1 (stable)        SQLite v3 Interface driver for PDO
SQLite     1.0.3 (stable)        SQLite database bindings
sqlite3    0.6 (alpha)           SQLite v3 Database Bindings.
ec2-user[~]> pecl download sqlite3
Failed to download pecl/sqlite3 within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.6, stability "alpha", use "channel://pecl.php.net/sqlite3-0.6" to install
download failed
ec2-user[~]> pecl download channel://pecl.php.net/sqlite3-0.6
downloading sqlite3-0.6.tgz ...
Starting to download sqlite3-0.6.tgz (768,302 bytes)
.........................................................................................................................................................done: 768,302 bytes
File /home/ec2-user/sqlite3-0.6.tgz downloaded
ec2-user[~]> sudo pecl install sqlite3-0.6.tgz
84 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
Optionally provide the path to the libsqlite3 library [autodetect] : yes
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root8Jljf1/sqlite3-0.6

(...)

/var/tmp/sqlite3/sqlite3.c:1586: error: duplicate 'static' // repeated lots of times
make: *** [sqlite3.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Edit: There is no `php-sqlite` or `php5-sqlite` package

```
ec2-user[~]> sudo yum search sqlite
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
========================================================================= N/S Matched: sqlite ==========================================================================
apr-util-sqlite.x86_64 : APR utility library SQLite DBD driver
libdbi-dbd-sqlite.x86_64 : SQLite plugin for libdbi
python-sqlite.x86_64 : Python bindings for sqlite.
python24-sqlite.x86_64 : Python bindings for sqlite.
sqlite-devel.x86_64 : Development tools for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine
sqlite-doc.x86_64 : Documentation for sqlite
sqlite-tcl.x86_64 : Tcl module for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine
perl-DBD-SQLite.x86_64 : Self Contained RDBMS in a DBI Driver
sqlite.i686 : Library that implements an embeddable SQL database engine
sqlite.x86_64 : Library that implements an embeddable SQL database engine
```

Edit 2: no package as above is also available after enabling the (disabled by default) [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel)

Comment: There is no `php5-sqlite` package available? Amazon AMI seems to be ubuntu installations.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: nope, see edit

Comment: What OS are you using? I know we use the utterramblings repo for our PHP5 installation on CentOS; http://www.jasonlitka.com/

Comment: Its Amazon Linux AMI http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Amazon AMI is now OK with this issue. My default PHP 5.4 installation from repos has SQLite3 support enabled.

```
[root@amazon-ami php.d]# php -m | grep sqlite
pdo_sqlite
sqlite3
[root@amazon-ami php.d]#
```

This code for example works fine for me:

```
$db = new SQLite3('localDB.sqlite');

$db->exec('CREATE TABLE test (foo STRING)');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO test (foo) VALUES ('bar')");

$results = $db->query('SELECT foo FROM test');

while ($row = $results->fetchArray())
    echo $row['foo'];
```

Comment: I am long past being able to verify this, but accept your answer as promised.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up abandoning EC2 for this, and settled for a Linux Mint in a VM.

If anyone knows the solution though I will be happy to accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

For sqlite on Amazon linux I did the following:

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```